# Can I boot my board from built-in emmc while the sd-card plugged in?

Tags: boot, sd-card, u-boot

This is kind like a U-Boot related question. I'm not quite sure which site should I post to, but as I boot Ubuntu, I post it here.

Basicly, I bought a cheap Nanopi Neo Air with Allwinner H3 SOC. I'm using the official ubuntu 20.04 image. I flashed the system into the onboard emmc with the eflasher tool provided.

The onboard emmc is too small for my use case, but it is faster than a sd-card. I want my system boot from emmc, while using sd-card as extra storage. So I formated my sd-card as one big ext4 partition, and rebooted my system.

When booting, my u-boot is not happy with a sd-card plugged in. It will always boot from the sd-card, even when it is empty (so it won't boot at all).

**What did I try**
I tried to purge all data in my sd-card by writing zeros into it. That did'nt help.

**What do I want**
Boot from emmc with sd-card plugged in

Any information appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is surely possible, but can't be answered generally, because the boot order and testing is individually defined in your U-Boot environment. For example, there can be some variable like `bootdevs` containing a list like `mmc emmc` saying to first try to boot from mmc, and if that fails, from emmc. In your case, I suspect there is a bad test implemented for mmc boot. Maybe it just checks whether the sdcard is there at all. This test must get extended to first test for a card to be present, then test for an ext4 filesystem, finally look for a file `/boot/vmlinuz` or whatever is the path of the kernel image.

If you don't have an explanation of your U-Boot configuration, it is no rocket science to reverse-engineer it. Do `printenv boot` in your U-Boot prompt and see what it does. It will probably run other commands, which you can also `printenv`. Maybe some command will not exist, because it get's generated during execution, so see the whole `printenv` output to see where and how it gets generated. The syntax is quite easy to learn.

If you can't manage it by yourself, post your `printenv` output here, so we can help you to debug and expand it.